# Want to access call_history.db in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to access call_history.db or I can say that want to get information of call list in iOS SDK.

I google for same so many time and get to know that, In library folder we have call_history.db file is there and we can access that.

I develop app as find all file ".db" file from library folder, But can't get anyone.

I developed that application for iOS 7.0 and Up, but can't get anything to work.

Comment: Its not possible, unless you are developing for a jailbroken device.

Comment: @SvetlanaSlutstokyovich :- As i search and got that till iOS 4 we can access. I just want to know that, it is possible or not.?

Comment: Its never been possible to access the call history if you want to publish in the app store. Technically you *can* access the call history, but you cannot put your app in the app store if you do.